# Travelling salesman problem with detours

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-hard, decision-problem, traveling-salesman

I am interested if there exists a following version of the travelling salesman problem:

> INSTANCE: A finite set $C = \{1,2,\dots,k\}$ of cities, a positive integer distance $\delta(i,j)$ for each pair of cities, and two positive integers $d$ and $B$.
>
> QUESTION: Is there a tour that visits every city in $C$, includes exactly $d$ detours, and has total length no more then $B$?  In other words, suppose $OPT$ is the optimal permutation of the cities; that is, $OPT(i)$ is the next city after city $i$ in an optimal traveling salesman tour.  Is there an ordering $x(0), \dots, x(k-1)$ of the cities such that $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \delta(x(i), x((i+1) \bmod k)) \leq B$$ and there are exactly $d$ indices $i$ where $x((i+1) \bmod k) \ne OPT(x(i))$?

The $d$ implies that if my shortest tour is $a\rightarrow b \rightarrow c\rightarrow a$ but $d=1$ then what would be the shortest path if I had to first go to $c$, $ a \rightarrow c \rightarrow ...$. So $d$ tells me that I have to make $d$ number of wrong choices but I can choose these choices in any way I want to to minimize the length of the path.

Is this a problem worthwhile describing? Or if it has been described where could I see an example?

Comment: You define it, it exists. However, I wonder why the formal definition of your question does not relate to $d$ at all.

Comment: I revised the formal statement to incorporate $d$, but please verify that I haven't changed the intent of the question.  A major issue with this formulation is that the optimal TSO tour is not unique; the reversal of any optimal TSP tour is another optimal TSP tour.

Comment: Maybe you can circumvent the issue raised by JeffE by asking for a tour which differs in exactly $d$ places from _some_ optimal tour $OPT$. In other words, there is atleast one optimal tour, from which the desired tour differs in $d$ places.

Comment: What would be an application of or a motivation for this problem?

Comment: To say d implies shortest length is wrong, wouldn't d make the number of length.